# Failed to trigger build: Couldn't read commit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket

I work with google cloud build and connect with bitbucket. The trigger have been work with a few build. But suddenly, I got the error like in the screenshot. I don't have any idea. What is it mean?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3xFP.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error usually shows when attempt to trigger build where there's no master branch exist.

Comment: I check on the source repo. It has the master branch and correct git commit number

Comment: If you believe this might be related to Cloud Build , you can report this here [1] to investigate this further.

https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=491371&template=1161230